# How do I change the default google search country for the location/search bar in Firefox 24+?

Tags: firefox, google-search

I usually search from the location/search bars in Firefox 24 ESR. Unfortunately, google thinks I'm in India and defaults to giving me "Indian results".

I'd like to change the search country via the search query string url, but the keyword.URL config parameter has been removed as part of [bug 738818](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738818), so this is no longer possible in current versions of Firefox.

What's the current method to change the default search country in the location/search bars ?

Comment: What's the value of the `general.useragent.locale` setting in [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)?

Comment: general.useragent.locale = en-US

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox modifying google searchplugin to not country redirect](http://superuser.com/questions/817087/firefox-modifying-google-searchplugin-to-not-country-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

keyword.URL was removed, as it is no longer needed. I liked it, but it really wasn't what you'd call user-friendly. Now you simply install a search engine in the search bar and it is used by default in the address bar too, unless you change it.

If you need to use google in a specific language, or in your case get rid of one, just install the appropriate google search engine to FF from the [Mycroft Project](http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom Google Search for your country from [this](http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html) URL.

Thereafter if you want further customization in Google Search, edit the XML file from Mozilla Profile:

E.g. for Windows7:

```
C:\Users\ < username >\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\< profile name >.default\searchplugins\google-xxx---from-xxx.xml
```

In my case, I have edited the 7th line to include Search Results from All countries but use google.ae using the below -

```
os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.ae/#q={searchTerms}&amp;tbas=0" resultDomain="google.ae"
```