# Firefox modifying google searchplugin to not country redirect

Tags: firefox, browser, search

I'm trying to modify the google.xml file in the browser/searchplugins folder in a way that it won't country redirect anymore. For example, to always reach the german google site, I have changed the last lines of the google.xml to this:

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.de/ncr/search">
  <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
......
</Url>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.de/ncr" rel="searchform"/>
```

At first, after restarting firefox, it didn't seem to have changed anything, however the next day when I started firefox, the changes seemed to have taken effect, because when I tried to google something, an Error Message was displayed aka "Uknown URL /ncr/search".

I now would like to know, how I can FORCE FF to reload the plugin immediately so I don't have to wait one day to test each change I made. Also it would be nice to know of course, how I need to modify the google.xml correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing more research, I found out that FF can be forced to reload modified searchplugins by deleting the `search.js` in `%AppData%\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\[ID].default\\` or the linux equivalent folder.

To actually get google to not redirect anymore, the following changes need to be made to the `google.xml` in the `....\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\searchplugins\\` folder:

in Line 13 change `google.com/search` to `google.de/search` or the TLD of your country. It should now be

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.de/search">
```

in Line 27 change `google.com` to `google.de/ncr`. It should now be

```
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.de/ncr" rel="searchform"/>
```

save it (Admin rights may be required). Delete the `search.js` mentioned earlier and restart firefox.

This got me working results for FF 32.0.3

UPDATE: In the FF35.0 Update, the syntax of the `google.xml` file seems to have changed. It's sufficient to change line 13 as mentioned above. Line 27 has been removed. Don't forget to delete the `search.js`

UPDATE 2: Since FF40.0, the default search plugin xmls are not available as plain text anymore. The new recommended way is to install the google US (no country redirect) search plugin from Mycroft (see answer below) and and modify the xml in FF's AppData Folder to one's needs.

Answer (score 2):

The following google.com/ncr search plugin works in Firefox 34.0.5:

Google (No country redirect) (google.com) by Mycroft Project [Review]

http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline. In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom Google Search for your country from [this](http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html) URL.

Thereafter if you want further customization in Google Search, edit the XML file from Mozilla Profile:

E.g. for Windows7:

```
C:\Users\ < username >\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\< profile name >.default\searchplugins\google-xxx---from-xxx.xml
```

In my case, I have edited the 7th line to include Search Results from All countries but use google.ae using the below -

```
os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://www.google.ae/#q={searchTerms}&amp;tbas=0" resultDomain="google.ae"
```